# In iPhone Radio and checkbox options work only on double click

Tags: html, css

I am using Label and image divs with radio inputs. Everything is working good except when I run that on Iphone radios and checkboxes work on double click only.

Test on :
https://vpcl.outgrow.co/phone

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what is causing it, but it may help you to use Modernizr. It allows you to detect whether a user is using a device that uses touch events or click events, and which can help with interactive responses on different devices.

I have have also found that sometimes If I have a hover I will have to double click because mobile doesn't use hover, Modernizr helps in cases like that as well.

Comment: Can you help how I can use Modernizr js in this case to detect whether it is because of double click or not.